# MVC 3: Test controllers VS integration tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I started with MVC quite recently because I heard that the major advantage of MVC is that it makes the application unit testable. After writing first unit tests I saw that it is not always simple to test controllers that have a lot of logic inside (send confirmation emails, use Session, context and other ASP Net statics). It takes me more time to write the unit test than the functionality and I am not convinced that this is useful.

I am tempted to move the business logic into a "Service" layer that eliminates of all ASP Net statics and which can be easily tested. Then to use Selenium for integration tests in order to test the whole functionality.

1. Did you got into the situation when testing an action is very complex (especially mocking the input and setting up environment)?
2. Did you find a good approach to have business logic in controllers. Or you found it better to use services and controllers code just relay on services calls?
3. In my opinion testing a controller is more equivalent to integration tests than to unit tests. What do you think about this?
4. Do you think that unit testing controllers has any advantage over integration tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Did you got into the situation when testing an action is very complex (especially mocking the input and setting up environment)?

This happens when your controllers have lot of dependencies and they are tightly wired to them. Unless it is an existing code and bringing the changes to code creates more trouble you should loosely couple the dependencies through interfaces or abstract classes and that makes unit testable so easy. You should even use wrappers around Session, Cache and like objects.

As @Dismissile suggests that first you have to re-factor your controllers and then unit testing will be easy.

> Did you find a good approach to have business logic in controllers. Or you found it better to use services and controllers code just relay on services calls?

Controllers are not the place to put business logic. All the business logic should be in the Model classes. The whole responsibility of the controller is to talk to the model and return a view, json or whatever back to the client. If you have complex business logic in the controllers you should move them to model classes.

Simply you should think about "Dump Views.. Thin Controllers.. Fat Models"!

> In my opinion testing a controller is more equivalent to integration tests than to unit tests. What do you think about this?

Integration testing is totally different from Unit testing. In integration testing you have to setup the application and run the test cases against it. Here you are testing the behavior of the total application in every test scenario and not a single unit. Unit testing is all about testing the functionalities of methods in a class. Testing a class or method in unit testing should be independent of other classes or methods.

But the thing is when designing an application unit testing should be kept in mind else unit testing will become as difficult as integration testing and of course it's not unit testing at all.

> Do you think that unit testing controllers has any advantage over integration tests?

Finding and fixing errors at unit level is so easy compared to the system level. So the answer is yes.

I think in your case you have an application that has controllers does more than what they have to do. So if you are thinking about unit testing so serious then you have to re-factor and loosely couple the dependencies wherever you need else there is no much gain in writing unit tests at all.

Answer (score 5):

> I am tempted to move the business logic into a "Service" layer that
>   eliminates of all ASP Net statics and which can be easily tested. Then
>   to use Selenium for integration tests in order to test the whole
>   functionality.

This pretty much right here. If your controllers are complex then they need to be refactored. They shouldn't have any business logic at all. You can using a Mock framework to mock the service layer and test your controllers easily that way.

> In my opinion testing a controller is more equivalent to integration
>   tests than to unit tests. What do you think about this?

I disagree with this. You are testing your controller to make sure it returns the appropriate response based on the input you give it. Supply an id that doesn't exist? Redirects to another page or returns a NotFound view. Model State is invalid? Returns the same view again, etc.

Comment: Couldn't be explained better or more concisely.